# Install mujoco for C++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, mujoco

I was trying to install Mujoco as a library to be used in my own Cpp programs, but I don¡t know if I should build it, although it does not have any CMakeLists file. I do not have much experience using precompiled libraries, so there might be the problem. Don't have much experience with Mujoco, but since I wanted to create a ROS2 interface with Mujoco, I think that going to the Mujoco library and learn how to use it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that we currently do not provide a `CMakeLists.txt` for MuJoCo. We are in the process of modifying our internal CMake setup to have it work for non-Google users. This will be made available as part of our open source release.

In the meantime, the [`CMakeLists.txt` for our Python bindings](https://github.com/deepmind/mujoco/blob/main/python/mujoco/CMakeLists.txt) should give you an idea for how to build a CMake project against the precompiled MuJoCo library.

Comment: If I want to use it in Cpp, should I just take the folder that is downloaded from the official page and put it either in my /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib folders? Again, I have no experience with manually installing shared libraries, so I might be making some mistakes, although I'm currently reading on it.

Comment: In the CMakeLists for Python that I linked to above, we defined CMake variables (`MUJOCO_LIBRARY` and `MUJOCO_INCLUDE`) that are used as hints to `find_library`. I _believe_ that if you put the MuJoCo library in /usr/local/lib (or any directory that's in your system's default library search paths list) then you should not need the hint.